# SSRS add event data and manually updating SSRS Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am not sure if this is the best way, but it work for me. THe only downside is I need to add a random seconds of delay in order to use the current parameter. 
Please look at my code below.

In SQL JOB of SSRS I modify step 1 of the SQL JOB. Prior to do exec addevent I update parameter value.

```
    declare @xml as xml
    set quoted_identifier ON
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT C.[City]
    FROM #FService C
    GROUP BY C.[City]
    ORDER BY C.[City]
    DECLARE @CityLoop VARCHAR(50);
    OPEN db_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @CityLoop;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    -- THIS IS TO UPDATE XML
    set @xml = (select  Parameters 
    from ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions sb
    where sb.SubscriptionID = 'GUID')
       set @xml.modify('    replace value of 
       (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[2]/Value/text())[1]    with    
       sql:variable("@CityLoop")  ')

    -- HERE WE UPDATE PARAMETER TABLE
    update ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions 
    set parameters = convert(nvarchar(max), @xml)
    where SubscriptionID = 'GUID'

    -- HERE IS THE ORIGINAL EXEC
    exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='GUID'

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30';

    --RAISERROR (@DealLoop, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT 

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @CityLoop;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Notice we add a 30 seconds delay for the SSRS to pickup and execute the report. 
is there a way to avoid random seconds and execute the report directly? or AddEvent is the only way to do this?

if I don't have a delay, the report will only run using the last @cityLoop parameter. that is why I add the delay then the job works properly by sending email every 30 seconds for each City that is available in the parameter query

I am using SSRS and SQL Server 2012

thank you for your help

Comment: You are updating a default parameter and then adding a record of action for a subscription. I bet that AddEvent is non blocking, meaning you are creating a record for action and nothing else. At some point later the SSRS agent will poll for activity and see the record you entered and start to do work, however, by this time the default value has been changed many times and will always reflect the latest value. The 30 delay is a risky way to achieve this as you are assuming the render and email will complete within 30 seconds.

Comment: Have you looked into Data Driven Subscriptions? --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/data-driven-subscriptions

Comment: Data-driven subscriptions are in Enterprise & Developer editions only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted this in order to solve the risky random wait times. 
SQL Server central article[https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dynamically-name-reportfile-export-in-ssrs]

It basically uses a wait for execution

```
            -- WAIT for EXECUTION
        set @bool1 = ISNULL((select eventdata from event where eventdata = @SBidEventData), '') 
        while  @bool1 <> ''
        begin 
            set @bool1 = ISNULL((select eventdata from event where eventdata = @SBidEventData), '') 
            if  @bool1 = '' 
            begin 
                -- SET PATH AND PARAMETER TO THE WAY IT WAS
                WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:07'
                update Catalog 
                set Path = '/Report/Report1'
                where ItemID = @ItemID
                update Subscriptions
                set Parameters = '<ParameterValues><ParameterValue><Name>Year</Name><Value>2019</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>Category</Name><Value>HONDA</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>Month</Name><Value>12</Value></ParameterValue></ParameterValues>'
                where SubscriptionID = @SBidEventData
            end
```

end